# Fonts in terminal overlapping

Tags: command-line, fonts, themes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why are letters overlapping in the terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/72023/why-are-letters-overlapping-in-the-terminal)

I'm having a problem with ubuntu where the characters are overlapping each other. How do i set it back to default?