# Why are letters overlapping in the terminal?

Tags: 11.10, command-line, virtualbox, fonts

I installed Oneiric as a guest OS in VirtualBox using the Mini CD. I installed the `ubuntu-desktop` package and everything seems to work fine - well, except for a font issue with the terminal:

[image]

As you can see, some of the letters overlap and it's difficult to read. I checked the settings and it the checkbox "Use the system fixed width font" is checked with "Monospace | 12" selected underneath it.

---

**Edit:** running the commands mentioned in the comments:

```
$ fc-match "Monospace"
DejaVuSansMono.ttf: "DejaVu Sans Mono" "Book"
$ gconftool --get /desktop/gnome/interface/monospace_font_name
Monospace 10
$ debsums ttf-dejavu-core
/usr/share/doc/ttf-dejavu-core/AUTHORS                                        OK
/usr/share/doc/ttf-dejavu-core/BUGS                                           OK
/usr/share/doc/ttf-dejavu-core/NEWS.gz                                        OK
/usr/share/doc/ttf-dejavu-core/README                                         OK
/usr/share/doc/ttf-dejavu-core/changelog.Debian.gz                            OK
/usr/share/doc/ttf-dejavu-core/copyright                                      OK
/usr/share/doc/ttf-dejavu-core/langcover.txt.gz                               OK
/usr/share/doc/ttf-dejavu-core/status.txt.gz                                  OK
/usr/share/doc/ttf-dejavu-core/unicover.txt.gz                                OK
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-dejavu/DejaVuSans-Bold.ttf                      OK
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-dejavu/DejaVuSans.ttf                           OK
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-dejavu/DejaVuSansMono-Bold.ttf                  OK
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-dejavu/DejaVuSansMono.ttf                       OK
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-dejavu/DejaVuSerif-Bold.ttf                     OK
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-dejavu/DejaVuSerif.ttf                          OK
```

Comment: Which terminal are you using? xterm or gnome-terminal?

Comment: What do `fc-match "Monospace"` and `gconftool --get /desktop/gnome/interface/monospace_font_name` return?

Comment: I don't know, but I also experienced this issue when upgrading from Ubuntu 11.04 to 11.10.
Later I re-installed Ubuntu 11.10 from scratch and I no longer have this issue.

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, thanks! [Instructions here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Comment: @ændrük: I have added the information to the question.

Comment: How about `debsums ttf-dejavu-core`?

Comment: @ændrük: There, added.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Turns out the [ttf-ubuntu-font-family](http://packages.ubuntu.com/ttf-ubuntu-font-family) [image: Install ttf-ubuntu-font-family] package somehow didn't get installed. Immediately after installing that package, the terminal font switched to the Ubuntu Monospace font and everything was readable again.

Comment: Ping me with a solution to above problem, so next time I can edit without bothering you...  ;)

Answer (score 3):

Open your terminal Go to Edit-->Profile Preferences and in general tab check "Use System fixed width font"

Answer (score 2):

I have seen this kind of problem in my friend's gnome terminal..
just go to edit --> profiles and change the settings of the font of your terminal..
it should solve your problem.. :)

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem. [This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/285836/letter-spacing-in-gnome-terminal?rq=1) may be related. [Bug #1166125](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gtk+3.0/+bug/1166125)

Removing package pango-graphite fixed the problem for me:

```
sudo apt-get purge pango-graphite
```

Answer (score 1):

1. sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool
2. goto tweak tool
3. goto fonts>monospace>
   select ubuntu mono regular 13pts

Answer (score 1):

I use ZSH and this was happening to me when using autocomplete.

The solution was to add this to `~/.zshrc.`:

`export LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8`

If you'd like to understand more, I recommend reading https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30479607/explain-the-effects-of-export-lang-lc-ctype-lc-all

Answer (score 0):

Go to Software Center and remove 'monospace font for pretty code listings and for the terminal'.

If that doesn't do it for you, try to remove Terminal (gnome_terminal), log out and log in and install the Terminal(gnome-terminal).

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by running:
gconf-editor /apps/gnome-terminal/profiles/Default

and unchecking  "Use System Font"

Answer (score 0):

I fixed mine by using custom font monospace regular on all fronts.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend [edit]ing this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on AskUbuntu.)