# Fonts corrupted, all look the same

Tags: 13.04, fonts

After I upgraded to Ubuntu 13.04 I have a problem with the fonts in some apps.
When I use gvim or fontconfig, all the fonts available look the same. It doesn't matter which one I chose, it always defaults to the same ugly default. When I try to choose a different font in gnome-terminal preferences, it crashes.

Font usage in libreoffice is fine.

I have removed all the files in /var/cache/fontconfig. I issued fc-cache -r. I removed ~/.fonts directory. I uninstalled and reinstalled all the ttf-* packages and some more.

What else can I try ?

Answer (score 3):

Removing the following packages fixed this for me:

- libpango1.0-common (1.28.2-0ubuntu1.1)
- pango-graphite (0.9.3-0.2ubuntu1)

I solved it uninstalling *pango-graphite* and *pango libs*.

gnome-terminal just crashed and among all the libs listed in the dump, there was something about libpango. I checked what package provided it using:

```
dpkg -S /path/to/thelib.so
```

( Sorry I don't type the exact file, I couldn't write it down )

Then I removed the package and the fonts suddenly worked again. Maybe it was an old lib that kept around from an old installation. Other Ubuntu desktops I own don't have this libs installed.

Comment: pango-graphite seemed to be the only thing I had to remove.