# Font messed up?

Tags: 13.04, fonts

What have I done?!

[image]

Compare that to:

[image]

You'll see that there's a slight difference.

Comment: Have you done anything in a custom ~/.fonts.conf ?

Comment: if you could, share the results of the command: xrdb --query

Comment: Q:Have you done anything in a custom ~/.fonts.conf ? 
A:No, not that I know.

Comment: Q:if you could, share the results of the command: xrdb --query
A:It just gives the help index... ( xrdb --help)

Comment: Sorry - it's xrdb -query - I added an extra dash.

Comment: No problem, mistakes are human, here's what you need:


*customization: -color
Xft.antialias: 1
Xft.dpi: 96
Xft.hinting: 1
Xft.hintstyle: hintslight
Xft.rgba: rgb

Comment: Thanks, that looks correct (Ubuntu Defaults). Let me do some more looking and see what I can figure out.

Comment: Wow.. they're really 2 different fonts.
Didn't notice until now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same problem had plagued me since my upgrade to 13.04 until I finally found this post:

[Fonts corrupted, all look the same](https://askubuntu.com/questions/299184/fonts-corrupted-all-look-the-same/299416)

A bug in pango-graphite is behind this.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pango-graphite/+bug/1176022

The following fixed it for me.

```
$ sudo apt-get purge libpango1.0-common pango-graphite
```

If you don't have libpango1.0-common installed it can be omitted from the command.

```
$ sudo apt-get purge pango-graphite
```

Comment: `[name]@[name]:~$ sudo apt-get purge libpango1.0-common pango-graphite
[sudo] password for phoenix: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libpango1.0-common
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'libpango1.0-common'
`
Something wrong with my repository settings?

Comment: No. It just means you don't have libpango1.0-common installed.  Omit that missing package from the command and just purge pango-graphite.

Comment: Thanks, every thing totally works now! but now I'm miss my messed up font, better get used to not-messed-up-fonts*
`* Not an actual word`