# Awkward Fonts in Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: fonts

I have installed Ubuntu 13.04 in Vmware Workstation. After 3 week from the installation, yesterday, Vmware showed me an error I could not read that as I blindly clicked on ok.

Since then the fonts in Ubuntu are appearing in awkward manner (see below).

Rest everything is ok except the overall fonts. I have tried resetting the Unity interface using dconf-config and also tried unity-tweak-tool to change the fonts. Bothmethods didn't work. I didn't want to reisntall Ubuntu again. Please provide a solution.

[image: see here]

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be a duplicate of [Fonts corrupted, all look the same](https://askubuntu.com/questions/299184/fonts-corrupted-all-look-the-same).

For me, something like this occured when I upgraded from 12.10 (or maybe it was 12.04?) to 13.04. It seemed to be fixed by

`sudo apt-get remove pango-graphite`