# How come my terminal's character spacing is off unless I uncheck "Use the system fixed width font"?

Tags: command-line, display, fonts

My terminal looks like this:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/T05ux.png]

unless I uncheck "Use the system fixed width font" in which case it looks like this:

[image]

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nRgLJ.png]

I noticed that the character spacing is off for applications other than the terminal. Am I missing fonts?

Comment: What's your current system fixed width font? Maybe it's not fixed width at all.

Comment: @DavidFoerster: how would I check?

Comment: Looks like the following fixed it: http://askubuntu.com/a/72085/195831