# Problem with terminal's font

Tags: 16.04, fonts

I recently installed Ubuntu 16.04. It's the terminal font that's been really bugging me. It's weirdly spaced. From the  [posts](https://askubuntu.com/questions/72023/why-are-letters-overlapping-in-the-terminal) I read, I think what I'm seeing is fixed spaced font, but I don't see an option to uncheck it in the menu anywhere. I'd appreciate any help I can get on this.

Update 1 : Attaching screenshot. 
[image]

Comment: Add a screenshot, please.

Comment: You're not using a fixed-width font, but a variable-width one, but the terminal isn't made to handle those. Change your font to one of the monospace ones (Ubuntu Mono, Deja Vu Mono, etc.)

Comment: Thanks! You are right! Changing the font worked. But I'm confused because this was working fine on Ubuntu :/

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed the [ttf-ubuntu-font-family](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=ttf-ubuntu-font-family) package?

Sometimes if not installed correctly, it can mess up word spacing.

Also, not sure if this applies in 16.06, from the terminal, then Edit Menu , then Profile Preferences and in the General tab re-check "Use System fixed width font"

Comment: The package is installed.  

I also tried looking for the checkbox but couldn't find it there.