# Ubuntu 12.04 Terminal Font appears smashed together regardless of font or font size. How do i fix this?

Tags: 12.04, command-line

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why are letters overlapping in the terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/72023/why-are-letters-overlapping-in-the-terminal)

When running terminal the font appears smashed with some characters overlapping. It makes it very difficult to follow along. Is there a reason and maybe a fix?

Comment: possible duplicate: [see here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/8822/fonts-in-terminal-overlapping) [and here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/72023/why-are-letters-overlapping-in-the-terminal)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open terminal <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>

Click at **Edit**, and go to **Profile Preference**.

[image]

In **General** tab, you can change your font and font size.

Comment: how do i add the menu bar to the terminal window?

Comment: @ penreturn: This is completely unrelated, but what theme are you using? It looks neat.

@user94527 If you are using Unity, the menu bar should be shown in the panel by default (global menu). On any other desktop environment just right click on the terminal window and select "show Menubar".

Comment: my menu bar is showing up at the top of the workspace as opposed to under the window buttons in terminal. but got the problem fixed anyway.

Comment: That default Unity.  @Glutanimate Thanks man. Check my [blog](http://penreturns.rc.my)

Comment: @penreturn Cheers, mate. Just installed the theme and it looks great!

Comment: @Glutanimate Enjoy Ubuntu!